# how to remove onclick from <form> and <button>

Tags: javascript, forms, button, onclick, action

Hello I have a problem with this following code :

```
<form id="signon_form"  method="post" action="r1.php" class="form-signin" name="">
  <div id="error" class="error">
    <img src="images/error_button.png" /> <span id="error_message"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="input_info_container">
    <div class="input_text">
      <label id="username_input_label" class="user_label" for=
      "username_input" style=""></label> <input id="username_input" name=
      "username" type="text" class="input_fields username_input" autocorrect=
      "off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" placeholder="example@email.ca"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input_info help_icon">
        <a id="help_icon" class="help_link" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" tabindex="3">
        <img src="images/icons/helpIcon.png"><br/>
        Help
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input_info_container">
    <div class="input_text">
      <label id="password_input_label" class="user_label" for=
      "password_input" style="">Password</label> <input id="password_input"
      name="password" type="password" class="input_fields" tabindex="2" />
    </div>

    <div class="input_info">
      <button type="button" id="account_number_popover_password" class=
      "account_number_popover ic icon-shaw-question" data-toggle="modal"
      data-target="#myModal"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <div id="checkbox-section" class="checkbox-section">
    <div id="checkbox" class="checkboxFive">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="persistent_check" name="" checked=
      "checked" tabindex="4"/> <label id="checkboxMask" class="ic" for=""></label>
    </div>

    <div id="checkbox-label" class="checkbox-label">
      <label>Remember Shaw email</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <button type="button" id="signin_submit" onclick="location.href='r1.php'" class=
    "button button_disabled"  tabindex="5">Sign in</button>
  </div>

  <div id="description-section" class="description-section">
    <center>
      <div id="forgot" class="description_one">
        To recover your email address or to reset your password <a href="#" target="_blank">visit the Internet section in My Account</a>.
      </div>

      <div id="create_new_account" class="description_two hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
        <span class="dont-have-account-phone">Don't have an account?</span>
        <a target="_self" data-event="navigation-element" data-value=
        "signon|body|create-one-now-link" id="create_one_now" href=
        "#"><span class=
        "dont-have-account-desktop">Don't have an account?</span>
        <span class="create-one-now-url">Create one now.</span></a>
      </div>
    </center>
  </div><input type="hidden" id="anchor" name="anchor" value="" />
</form>
```

you see that I have an action in the form which is `r1.php` and the button has a `onclick="location.href='r1.php'"` if I delete it the Sign In button doesn't work I want to get rid of it can you help me guys I'm a begginer and experimenting with website's source code to learn a little please if you could help me I'll be so greatfull

Comment: A form **needs** an `action`; it tells the form where to send the data. If you are trying to send it to the page you are currently on, simply use `action='#'`.

Comment: I gaved it the action="r1.php" because I want it to go to the page r1.php

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an actual form **submission**, rather than a simple redirection.

Instead of:

```
<button type="button" id="signin_submit" onclick="location.href='r1.php'" class="button button_disabled" tabindex="5">Sign in</button>
```

You need an `input` type of `submit`:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="signin_submit">
```

This tells the button to actual **POST** the data. Note that you may need to slightly tweak your CSS to give the desired display.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah thanks this really helped I'll tested out right now

Comment: The existing button could just be changed to type submit (or the type attribute omitted since buttons default to submit).

Comment: Glad to hear this solution appears to have worked for you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)